Closest equivalent to UIImage for audio files in Swift
I need to download and process audio from an api that returns an url.
I can download the audio as data using the session object:
}
@objc func download(surl: NSString, completion : @escaping (NSData) -> Void ) {
    guard let url = URL(string: String(surl)) else { return }     
    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        if let data = data, error == nil {
            let nsdata = NSData(data: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(nsdata)//returns the audio as NSData
            }
        } else {
          //fail
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

With the resulting NSData if it was an image I could do
        if let img = UIImage(data: data as Data) {
           do something with my image
        }

However I'm unclear how best to hold and work with my audio data eg save, move etc.
Can you keep it in the form of anything more precise than Any or NSData?
I believe you can play it as an url using avplayer:
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url: url)
            player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: playerItem)
            player?.play()   

However, is there a container equivalent to UIImage or do you just deal with audio using urls, NSData Any etc.
Thanks for any suggestions

Why not save the data into a local file? AVPlayerItem doesn't work on local URL?

I do need to save locally as well as on a server. However, I'm wondering in what format?  Just generically as NSData?  Or is there anything specific to audio.  For example with UIImage you  first of all know that is actually an image as opposed to something else and you have UIImagePNGRepresentation(self) and other things so that you can work with the image eg change its format etc.  I'm looking for something more specific to audio than just NSData which seems to be a black box.  You don't know if it's in fact an audio and if so an Mp3, wav or whatever.

(NS)Data is just a wrapper around "Bytes". It's raw data. Any file is data, it's just that they follow some protocols. Also I guess that audio files are optimized so that you can just read the start of the file if needed, etc not loading the whole file (which can be heavy).

It's unclear what kind of thing you are looking for? What characteristics of UIImage should your desired type have in common? Why is AVPlayerItem not what you are looking for? What about AVAsset, or AVAudioFile?

maybe those are what I am looking for.... When I download an image I generally hold it initially as a UIImage. I can resize a UIImage, changes its background and and do a lot of stuff with it. I can get its png representation etc. So I'm looking for a wrapper around NSData that knows the NSData is an audio file. When I download the audiofile as NSData, I don't know if it's a valid audio file or even file, its format as in mp3 or anything else about it.

I don't know how, if it is possible, to save it as an mp3 as you can get a pngrepresentation of a UIImage.  I will try converting the NSData as an AVAudioFile and the other two suggestions and see what properties or methods become available that let you work with the file.

The rough equivalent of UIImage for audio is AVAsset. It represents "the media" in a form independent of its format.
As a rule, you do not hold audio or video in a Data because they are generally drastically larger than a single image and you will incur significant memory pressure. You can write them to disk and access them via a file URL.
Since holding audio or video as Data is an extremely rare use case, there are few conveniences for it. You would need to manage it yourself as Data and feed it to a AVSampleBufferAudioRenderer.
On Mac, there is also NSSound which supports constructing very small audio clips directly from Data.


So I'm looking for a wrapper around NSData that knows the NSData is an audio file

There isn't some simple mindless sound file container similar to UIImage; the sound file is just data from the UIKit point of view. You can use the audio format services to get information about your sound file data.
